# Thin clients over WAN - Capacity planning

Tags: cloud, xen, citrix, thin-client

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

How reliable is it to run thin clients such as Citrix XenDesktop over the WAN.  I am designing an IT solution where the client will have his desktop hosted and managed remotely as a service.  The WAN connection will most likely be a cable connection with 40 Mbps.  I remember a SunRay thin client solution pushing a solid 10 mbps of LAN traffic and this was with 50+ simultaneous users so I don't anticipate bandwidth to be an issue.  I anticipate using Citrix XenDesktop however I am not the best at capacity planning.  I plan on getting a box with one or two of the newest I7s and 32 GB of RAM.  How many users can I reliably fit onto this?

Comment: Thanks, but that gets you into a circular argument.  You can't really know how much capacity you need until you test the system but you can't design the system without knowing what to buy.  There are general "rules of thumb" that "people who've been doing it for years" just simply know.  For example I know that Wordpress\Joomla sites with > 200k unique hits should be off a shared server.  Shared servers (in my environment) tend to die after this point and we have to kick users off.  I know they can also handle < 30 simultaneous HTTP connections.  I know simply having worked in the environment.

Comment: Would this be better asked on Serverfault?

Comment: This seems like it belongs on Server Fault.

Comment: ya sorry.  Didn't know if it should be here or Server Fault.  I'll remake.  You can disregard this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This two links are a bit old (2010), but should give you some rough idea.

[XenDesktop Planning Guide: User Bandwidth Requirements](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX126191)

[How Much Bandwidth Do I Need for My Virtual Desktop?](http://blogs.citrix.com/2010/05/20/how-much-bandwidth-do-i-need-for-my-virtual-desktop/)

Following chart should be most interested to you

[image]